# How can we set a variable after the user chooses from a HighLine menu in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, variables, menu, highline

The HighLine documentation shows that we can display a string after the user selects an option from the list, like follows:

```
choose do |menu|
  menu.prompt = "Please choose your favorite programming language?  "

  menu.choice(:ruby) { say("Good choice!") }
  menu.choices(:python, :perl) { say("Not from around here, are you?") }
end
```

How can we set a variable in addition to (or in place of) showing text? Replacing `say("Good choice!")` with `variable = 1` did not work and instead returned an "undefined local variable or method" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local variables are destroyed when a method/block/proc finishes executing.  But, you can make it so that `variable` is not a local variable of the block:

```
variable = nil

choose do |menu|
  variable = 1
  menu.prompt = "Please choose your favorite programming language?  "

  menu.choice(:ruby) { say("Good choice!") }
  menu.choices(:python, :perl) { say("Not from around here, are you?") }
end

puts variable
```

A block creates what's called a `closure`, which means that it can see the variables that were in existence outside the block when the block was CREATED.  On the other hand, a block cannot see the variables outside the block at the time it is EXECUTED--even if the variables have the same names as the variables the block *can* see.  For instance,

```
def do_stuff(&block)
  x = 1
  block.call
end

x = 10
do_stuff {puts x}

--output:--
10
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. So if I'm understanding this correctly, any variables created within the block will be destroyed at the end, losing whatever value they stored. Yet if the variable was created prior to the block, it will retain whatever value is given to it within the block?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR response is simply that you need to define a variable accessible outside of your block scope.

First off, check out the documentation of the API:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/highline/HighLine#choose-instance_method

You'll see `def choose( *items, &details )`, so the choose method takes any length of arguments, and then also a block. The block is where you see `do ... end` being handed to the choose call:

```
choose do |menu|
  menu.choice(:meow) {|q| q = 'foo'}
end
```

Ok, so we see another method, which is `choice`: http://rubydoc.info/gems/highline/HighLine/Menu#choice-instance_method

```
# File 'lib/highline/menu.rb', line 136

def choice( name, help = nil, &action )
  @items << [name, action]

  @help[name.to_s.downcase] = help unless help.nil?
  update_responses  # rebuild responses based on our settings
end
```

Now let's break down `.choice(:meow) {|q| q = 'foo'}` using what we see from `choice`. It expects a name `(:meow)`, defaults a help to nil if none is provided (so in my example call it is nil), and finally takes another block which is `{|q| q = 'foo'}`.

My example evaluates to:

```
1. meow
?  1
 => "foo"
q
=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `q' for main:Object
```

Why? because q is defined only within the scope of the block being passed in. You can't access it once that proc is evaluated. So what you need to do is this:

```
1.9.3-p448 :015 > choose do |menu|
1.9.3-p448 :016 >     menu.choice(:meow) { @foo = 'foo'}
1.9.3-p448 :017?>   end
1. meow
?  1
 => "foo"
1.9.3-p448 :018 > @foo
 => "foo"
```